# Cannot call abortTransaction after calling commitTransaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, transactions

I am getting the following error in my application logs:

> MongoTransactionError: Cannot call abortTransaction after calling commitTransaction

The code below shows the function in which this error occurs. The
commitTransaction() is at the very end of the "try" block so there
should be no way that the transaction is being commited and still ends up in the
catch block. I checked if maybe there is some other code path branching off from
this function which calls commitTransaction but that's definitely not the case.

Another possibly related error that I
also see appearing in the application logs is:

> MongoServer Error: Given transaction number 28 does not match any in-progress
> transactions. The active transaction number is 27.

Again I don't see how this could happen given the try/catch/finally block that
I am using. As far as I know sessions are totally isolated. Other parts of the
code that start their own session should never conflict or interact with
transactions in this session (right?). Do transaction numbers within a session
start at 0, if so the mention of transaction number 27 would suggest multiple
transactions are being executed in this session which shouldn't be the case, since I am ending the session in the finally block.

Any help or pointers are appreciated as I've been stuck at this for days now.

```
async deleteArticle(id, options={}) {
  let modifiedArticles = [id];
  let modifiedAuthors;
  let modifiedDuplicateSets;

  const session = this.connection.startSession();
  try {
    session.startTransaction();     
    const deletedArticle = await this.articles.delete(id, { session });

    let {
      partitionCount,
      createdDuplicateSets,
      removedDuplicateSets,
      modifiedDuplicateArticles,
    } = await this.articles.partitionDuplicateSet(deletedArticle.duplicateSetId, { session });

    modifiedAuthors = deletedArticle.authorIds;
    modifiedArticles.push(...modifiedDuplicateArticles);
    modifiedDuplicateSets = unique([
      deletedArticle.duplicateSetId,
      ...createdDuplicateSets,
      ...removedDuplicateSets
    ]);
    let articleCountDelta = -1 + partitionCount;

    for (let authorId of deletedArticle.authorIds) {
      if (await this.isUnusedAuthor(authorId, { session })) {
        await this.deleteAuthor(authorId, { session });
      } else {
        await this.authors.incrementArticleCount(authorId, articleCountDelta, { session });
      }
    }

    await session.commitTransaction();
    return { modifiedArticles, modifiedAuthors, modifiedDuplicateSets };
  } catch(error) {
    await session.abortTransaction();
    throw error;
  } finally {
    await session.endSession();
  }
}
```

Details:

- Using mongodb nodejs client 4.9.1
- Using node v16.20.1